# facebook login button logout text

Tags: html, button, facebook, fbml

so i have this facebook login button:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>
```

but then once you log in, the log out button text gets really long

how can I change the text displayed on the logout button so that it's shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi
In my application I check if the user is is logged in or not and give the button text text accordingly.

```
if( $this->loggedIn ){
    $button = '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday" onlogin="window.location.reload(true);" autologoutlink="true">Logout</fb:login-button>';
    }
    else {
        $button = '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>';
    }
```

Hope this will work for you too